# Can temporary storage be avoided when overloading binary operators?

Tags: fortran, operator-overloading, fortran2008

I was using operator overloading for a vector class

```
interface operator(+)
  module procedure :: vec_add_sv  !< scalar + vector
  module procedure :: vec_add_vs  !< vector + scalar
  module procedure :: vec_add_vv  !< vector + vector
end interface operator(+)
            :
            :
function vec_add_sv( s, v1 ) result( v2 )
  type(Vector)             :: v2
  real(dp),     intent(in) :: s
  type(Vector), intent(in) :: v1
  integer :: i, n
  n = v1%size()
  call v2%resize(n)
  do i=1,n
    V2%q(i) = s + V1%q(i)
  end do
end function vec_add_sv
            :
            :
v2 = s + v1
```

works just fine. However when I implemented:

```
interface assignment(=)
  module procedure vector_assign
end interface assignment(=)
```

and put write statements in both the function **vec_add_sv** and the subroutine **vector_assign** I noticed that when I used

```
vec2 = scalar + vector
```

it called both the **vec_add_sv** function and the **vector_assign** subroutine. This indicates that the **vec_add_sv** function created a temporary vector for its return and then passed that temporary to the **vector_assign** subroutine. The result is that I am looping through my vector elements twice.

Is there a way to implement binary operators with out creating temporary storage?

I recognize that a temporary is needed if you do something like A = B + ( C * D ) then (C * D) crates a temporary that is used in B + temp.
But if I am just doing a single operation A = B + C

I would like something equivalent to

```
interface add
  subroutine vec_add( A, B, C )
    type(vector), intent(out) :: A
    type(vector), intent(in)  :: B
    type(vector), intent(in)  :: C
  end subroutine vec_add
end interface add
```

interface **operator(+)** requires the module procedure to be a **function** not a subroutine

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You can add a version tag to specify. Almost no-one saw your question, becuse it had a tag that people don't follow.

Comment: [tag:fortran2008]: 16 followers, [tag:fortran]: 3200 followers. Tags are very important at StackOverflow.

Comment: *"This indicates that the vec_add_sv function created a temporary vector for its return and then passed that temporary to the vector_assign subroutine. "* Why do you think it indicates that? Compilers can do many clever things to avoid temporaries. Maybe there is a temporary created, but that should be confirmed first.

Comment: Why do you need your own `vector_assign` routine? Why is intrinsic array assignment insufficient?

Comment: SteveES, because all arguments are pointers, the linker can not distinguish between   ( scaler, array ) and ( array, scaler ) nor can it distinguish between ( A, B ) and ( B, A ) when A(:) and B(:,:) when creating generics such as operator overloading.

Comment: Disregard I just learned that since dummy arguments are keywords, just changing the name of the reference/keyword disambiguates the procedures.   `subroutine mul( vec, mat )` and `subroutine mul( mat, vec )` are ambiguous, but `subroutine mul( rowvec, mat )` and `subroutine mul( mat, colvec )` are not.

Comment: Vladimir - I added global counters to the operator, assign, and final procedures and counted the number of objects that went out of scope. executing A = B + C  at the end of the block 4 objects where finalized, 1 operator was executed and 1 assign was called.

Comment: You counted how many times the procedure got called, but you don't know for sure that the compiler copied the result to the variable or if it reused the storage of the function result for the variable, once that the result would go out of scope and no operations were done before assigning. Try using a Debug tool and compare the address of the underlying arrays.